# What's the effect of changing this condition in this Java function to find palindromes?

Tags: java, string

I am wondering how changing this condition will change the way the function works:

```
public static boolean palindrome(String str) {
     int i = 0;
     int j = str.length() - 1;


     while(i < j) { // This condition
          if(str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j)) {
              return false; 
          }

          i = i + 1;
          j = j - 1;
     }
     return true;
}
```

Changing it as follows:

```
public static boolean palindrome(String str) {
     int i = 0;
     int j = str.length() - 1;

     while(i <= j) { // Change is here
          if(str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j)) {
              return false; 
          }

          i = i + 1;
          j = j - 1;
     }
     return true;
}
```

They seem to both detect palindromes. The second one takes one more step. I don't see how this changes anything.

Thank you!

Comment: When i is equal to j you're comparing the character to itself, so code in second example adds an unneccessary step in this case.

Comment: Adding redundant checks won't change the output, just make it take longer.  You don't have to check past the midpoint in palindrome detection the same way you don't have to check past the square root for prime detection.

Comment: It should be the same amount of loops for even lengthed inputs (1221, abccba), but take one more loop for odd lengthed inputs (121, abcba).  It will compare the middle value to itself, which is unneeded because it should always be equal

Answer (score 1):

Between `while(i < j)` and `while(i <= j)` The difference is that the second one has one additional step because in the end, you are comparing `i` with `j` as suppose just everything less than `j`

Example with input `abcba`:

```
// First Code Indices Checked (i and j)
0 < 4
1 < 3
2 < 2 //fails, done

// Second Code Indices Checked (i and j)
0 <= 4
1 <= 3
2 <= 2 //passes, continues
3 <= 1 //fails, done, unneeded comparison
```

> And just like @azurefrog said : "You don't have to check past the
>   midpoint in palindrome detection"

Comment: a/b/c were just variables i used to show comparison that would happen in the loop, i have changed it to use numbers.

Comment: to follow up on your edit, what are 1/2/3?  Are they indices, values, constants?

Comment: the number on the left side would be the i variable and the left side would be the j variable when in the when()

Comment: in that case, wouldn't the left side increment and the right side decrement?  Currently I only see the left side incrementing and the right side being static.  Also, `i` should start out at 0, not 1

Comment: @phflack I formatted to match the question better, hope that makes sense

Comment: I think you were more on the right track showing the indices being compared, I suggested an edit that might clear things up

Comment: @phflack It comes down to the same thing where there is an added comparison in the end in the second loop